# Get Audio frame from AVCaptureSession

Tags: swift, avcapturesession

I have a running `AVCaptureSession`

```
public class MeetingViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {


private lazy var videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
private lazy var audioOutput = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()
```

and Setup it like that

```
 func setupCaptureSession(camera: AVCaptureDevice.Position = .front) {
            
        guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: camera) else {
            fatalError("Error getting AVCaptureDevice.")
        }

        guard let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device) else {
            fatalError("Error getting AVCaptureDeviceInput")
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
            self.captureSession?.sessionPreset = .hd1280x720
            self.captureSession?.addInput(input)
            
            self.videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
            self.videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: .main)
            
            self.captureSession?.addOutput(self.videoDataOutput)
            self.rotatePreview()
            
            // Set up audio output
            let audioOutput = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()

            let audioQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "audioQueue", qos: .userInteractive)
            audioOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: audioQueue)

            if ((self.captureSession?.canAddOutput(audioOutput)) != nil) {
                self.captureSession?.addOutput(audioOutput)
            } else {
                Logger.logError("Failed to add audio output to capture session.")
                return
            }
            
            self.captureSession?.startRunning()
        }
    }
```

And `captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)`

I modify the video frame a lot, and tried to make a video from modified `CVPixelBuffer` and store it. But I need the audio frame to add to the stored video. That is why I setup `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput` in `setupCaptureSession` function. and here:

```
 public func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        
        if isRecording {
            if output == audioOutput {
                // Process audio samples
                if videoRecorder != nil {
                    videoRecorder?.processAudioSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer)
                }
            }

        }
      ...
```

I tired to capture audio frame, but `output == audioOutput` always fails and I couldn't grab the audio frame, any suggestion here?

In addition, here is AVCaptureDeviceInput in viewDidLoad

```
   guard let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.audio) else {
        print("audio Device is not available")
        return
    }
    
    do {
        let audioInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice)
        self.captureSession?.addInput(audioInput)
    } catch {
        print("Unable to add audio device to the recording.")
    }
```

When I check, looks like the microphone is never becoming on (got its permission), anyone can help me what is the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your `audioOutput`and `audioInput`  are actuallying being added? What happens if you don't set a `sessionPreset`?